# Error in creating juju bootstrap

Tags: ubuntu, juju

I installed MAAS, added the Nodes and created the juju but while i tried the following code

```
juju bootstrap
```

I am getting this error.

```
WARNING no tools available, attempting to retrieve from https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/
ERROR gomaasapi: got error back from server: 404 Not Found
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on localhost or on AWS environment? If it is AWS have you inserted the AWSAccessKeyId and AWSSecretKey on proper locations?

Answer (score 0):

Although rather late at answering this, the question is still getting views. So this can happen because Juju can't see the MAAS API. You can add the MAAS cloud via `juju add-cloud` and then that will walk you through the required steps.